# How to Traverse an fields of Record in delphi2010?

Tags: delphi

I want to read fields of a record to a string list or an array of edit controls.  My code is error, please  fix it; and how to Write traversal the fields.

```
type
  TItem = record
   a : string[20];
   b : word;
   c  : word;
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
 uses rtti;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  rttiContext: TRttiContext;
  rttiType: TRttiType;
  fields: TArray<TRttiField>;
  item: TItem;
  i:word;
begin
  item.a:='hello';
  item.b:=123;
  item.c:=456;
  rttiType := rttiContext.GetType(TypeInfo(TItem));
  fields := rttiType.GetFields;
   for i := low(fields) to high(fields) do
   begin
    ShowMessage(fields[i].GetValue(@item).AsString);
   end;

end;

end.
```

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: Since he is using TRttiContext it should be 2010 or XE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to change `string[20]` to `string` (I do not know why and I do not know how to get it to work with `string[20]`).
And change `AsString` to `ToString`. This is tested on Delphi XE and Delphi 2010.

```
type
    TItem = record
     a : string;
     b : word;
     c  : word;
    end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
    rttiContext: TRttiContext;
    rttiType: TRttiType;
    fields: TArray<TRttiField>;
    item: TItem;
    i:word;
begin
    item.a:='hello';
    item.b:=123;
    item.c:=456;
    rttiType := rttiContext.GetType(TypeInfo(TItem));
    fields := rttiType.GetFields;
     for i := low(fields) to high(fields) do
     begin
        ShowMessage(fields[i].GetValue(@item).ToString);
     end;
end;
```

Comment: string[20] is a ShortString, while string is a UnicodeString. I don't have a Delphi 2010+ here, but it's possible ShortString is not supported with the new RTTI code.

Comment: @Jens: ShortString is ok. Array types is not. I think that is why string[20] does not work.

Comment: if i must be use array [0..32]of widechar and my record is a variantrecord , Code can not be compiled,How should I do

Comment: @baba I do not know. You should ask that in a new question so others can answer.